# How to find X, Y Coordinates on wooden plane

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm working on a wooden cnc machine.
How to calculate the x, x coordinates?
I have a square 300mm x 300mm

I want my point to be on a circle and to find the x, y to drill a hole.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Check out practicalmachinist.com if you want to know the optimized speeds and feeds. Does your control have polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

To find location of drill center, the parametric equations for  $ x-$  and $y-$ co-ordinates are:

$$ X = R+ R \cos \theta , Y = R+ R \sin \theta $$

To calculate them the radius $R$ must be known.( R= 150 approx).  $ \theta = 240^0$ in counter-clockwise direction.

$$ X= 225 , Y = 279.904 $$